# How to add a front-end framework (React, Vue, etc.) to SailsJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, sails.js

I'm trying to add React to an existing SailsJS app. The Sails docs say that you can use any front-end framework, but I didn't see in the docs how to do this properly

Answer (score 2):

You can add the compiled frontend files to the [assets](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/assets) folder, e.g. `/assets/index.html` or `/assets/js/script.js`.